# What does it take to institute Hallel?

Tags: hallel, yom-haatzmaut, yom-yerushalayim

What are some of the classical references for instituting Hallel b'zman hazeh? And in a more discussion-oriented vein, what kind of miracle do you think it would take for the vast majority of klal Yisrael to agree on a new day for Hallel? Clearly Yom Ha'atzmaut and Yom Yerushalayim have not yet caught on in the broader charedi/yeshivish communities.

Comment: Why do you write "not yet caught on"? First of all, no Rabbanim  institute additions and changes in tefillah based on what will "catch on". Secondly, who says those days will ever be respected by the haredi/yeshivish communities?

Comment: @Yahu, I suppose Jeremy is saying that those communities have not embraced those two dates as worthy of celebration, certainly not so great as to warrant additions to prayers, and I suppose the question is, what exactly would be deemed so great a miracle as to stir those communities (and everyone else in sync with them) to institute additional prayers of thanksgiving to HaShem?

Comment: @msh210 Why do either of those tags apply?

Comment: @DoubleAA, if I were asking this, I'd tag it with neither. But the asker used one, so I added the other. Anyway, the Q touches on both days, and someone interested in Qs about the days may well wish to see this.

Answer (score 6):

There is a famous Meiri (Rishon) which says that if an individual  or a community experienced a salvation, they may recite Hallel every year on that day without a bracha. This is why some people say Hallel without a Bracha on Yom Hatzmaut.

> מאירי פסחים קיז.‏
>   כל יחיד שאירעתהו צרה ונגאל הימנה
>   רשאי לקבוע הלל לעצמו באותו יום
>   בכל שנה אלא שאינו מברך עליו וכן
>   הדין בכל ציבור וצבור כך היה יסוד
>   נביאים לאמרו על כל צרה וצרה
>   כשנגאלים ממנה.‏

Answer (score 1):

Classical texts (Rishonim) that I've seen talk about an obligation to say Hallel in recognition of great events benefiting the Jewish People.

As far as what it would take for agreement on a new day of Hallel, I personally think that Chanukkah is a great example. Like Yom Haatzmaut, it marked a return to Jewish sovereignty. But also similarly, there were many people, including some of the "Gedolim" of that generation who were very anti Chashmonaim. This is reflected in the Mishna's exclusion of Chanuka completely and the Gemara's relatively minor mention of it.

But eventually all Jews came to celebrate it. Also, in the Charedi community change is very very slow. I personally think that eventually the vast majority of Jews will come to celebrate Yom Haatzmaut, probably even with Hallel, but it will probably take another few decades.

Comment: Meir, Welcome to mi.yodeya, and thanks very much for this perspective! I look forward to seeing you around.

Comment: I think you are underestimating the degree of the opposition of some groups to the existence of the State of Israel, as well as the degree of danger that the State faces every day, not to mention the demographic trends that suggest that those who do celebrate it will likely become the minority in a few generations (assuming both that the State survives and that the final Geulah doesn't come about by then).

Comment: I don't believe that R' Yehuda Hanasi didn't celebrate chanuka.

Comment: what makes you think that saying hallel on yom haatzmut will catch on anywhere other than in the "modern orthodox" and other "zionist leaning groups" that already say it?

Comment: @Dude Because just like last time it took a while for all Jews to catch on to a good thing, so too here. (This is what the OP says in his post. I don't know what you found unclear about that.)

Comment: @DoubleAA only if you assume this is a good thing that people will want to catch onto and not actually against halacha

Comment: @Dude Yes. Unfortunately people nowadays are often slow to admit mistakes. One day soon all will be Emet.