# Should Hallel be recited on Yom Yerushalayim

Tags: halacha, hallel, yom-yerushalayim

Should Hallel be recited on Yom Yerushalayim? I know that many rabbis hold on each side of this dispute so I'd like answers and justifications for those answers from both sides.

Comment: See also https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/1512

Comment: The answers from both sides are "yes" and "no".

Comment: @DanF How is that a duplicate?

Comment: @Daniel I believe it's a dupe b/c of what the OP has in his 1st sentence as well as the question title - "Should it be said". That answer lists the opinions of whether it should or not. In the answer which lists several rabbis, some explain their opinion as well. I've added my own answer quoting another reasoning, here. Although, the practice that I have seen is far from "mainstream", but it seems to be gaining some popularity, at least in my mainly Orthodox neighborhood.

Comment: @DanF That question is about which _gedolim_ say to recite hallel. This question is about _whether_ hallel should be said and why. Just because the _answer_ to the other question lists some justifications doesn't mean the _questions_ are duplicates.

Comment: @Daniel debatable. Gedolim are rabbis and current rabbis (most - not all) follow the suggestions of the gedolim.

Comment: @DanF My point is the other question does not request persuasive answers to the question of whether hallel should be recited. It just requests a list. My question requests a ruling and a reason for the ruling.

Comment: That wasn't that clear from your question title. If all you seek is the reasoning, knowing that there are differences, you may want to edit your question title and content to something like "What are the reasons for saying or not saying Hallel on Yom Yerushalayim". If, that's what you are seeking, I will reverse my vote. I also think my answer below explains one reason for why some say it only on Yom Yerushalayim.

Comment: @DanF Even if the question were just "Should hallel be recited' without any request for justification, it wouldn't be a duplicate. It would be a "yes" or "no" question as opposed to the other one which is a list question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59334/discussion-between-danf-and-daniel).

Comment: @close voter, I don't see how this question is about "the Hebrew language or about history or news of the Jewish people, Jewish individuals, or the State of Israel, except as related to Judaism". This is a question about halacha.

Answer (score 1):

I have seen a number of Orthodox places / yeshivot (a few in my neighborhood) that are more inclined to say Hallel on Yom Yerushalayim and not on Yom Ha'atzma'ut. Part of it is a "political" statement. They don't "believe" in the current state of Israel with its secular government and philosophy. But, they agree on the importance, significance and holiness of Yerushalayim, and esp. that the main result of the 6 Day war restored access to the Kotel.