# Miracles warranting public Torah reading or omission of Tachanun

Tags: miracle, yom-haatzmaut, yom-yerushalayim

Miracles happened and will happen to Israel. For example, on Purim and Chanukkah the *Tachanun* is omitted and/or [Hallel is recited](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/1512/what-does-it-take-to-institute-hallel/) and/or the Torah is publicly read. Today, on Jerusalem Day or recently on [Yom HaAtzmaut,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independence_Day_(Israel)#Religious_customs) many, mainly Zionist Jews deviate from the normal weekday prayer, and add parts they consider to be a proper expression of their joy.

Strictly from a *halakhic* point of view, what has to happen that warrants a public Torah reading or the omission of the *Tachanun?*

Comment: Very related (possibly a duplicate, but that question doesn't address torah reading / tachanun) https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/1512/what-does-it-take-to-institute-hallel/

Comment: Also related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/82917/reciting-hallel-on-yom-yerushalayim?rq=1

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_Purim https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Megillat_Taanit

Comment: Also related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/51262/11532

Comment: This really sounds like two questions: one for Torah reading and one for _tachanun_.

Comment: @msh210 I'd like to understand the mechanics of _chazal's_ decision about Chanuka and Purim. If such a great miracle happens tomorrow, what should our rabbis take into consideration.